# Proving the equality of two expressions

Tags: regression

The context of the following identity is in the Classical Normal Linear Regression Model, ie, $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}+ \boldsymbol{u}$ where $\boldsymbol{u}$ is a $n \times 1$ matrix and $u_i \sim iid.N(0, \sigma^2)$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$

Show that $(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})'(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}) = (\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b})'(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b})+(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{b})'\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X}(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{b})$

where:

$\boldsymbol{y}$ is a $n \times 1$ matrix

$\boldsymbol{X}$ is a $n \times k$ matrix

$\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a $k \times 1$ matrix

$\boldsymbol{b}$ is a $k \times 1$ matrix

$rank(\boldsymbol{X}) = k$

$\boldsymbol{b} = (\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{y}$

I can prove this expression by going from the RHS to LHS, however, I am not sure how to go from the LHS to the RHS (just assume that the expression on the RHS isn't known at first). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V = \mathrm{Im}(X)$ (it is a linear subspace of the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) and $\Pi_{V}$ be the orthogonal projection on $\mathrm{Im}(X)$.

In the following, if $z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, ${}^t z$ will denote the transpose of $z$. Let's first notice that :

$$ {}^t (y-X\beta)(y-X\beta) = \Vert y-X\beta \Vert^{2} $$

Which we can also write :

$$ \Vert y-\Pi_{V}(y) + \Pi_{V}(y) - X\beta \Vert^{2} $$

By definition, $\Pi_{V}(y) \in \mathrm{Im}(X)$ and $X\beta \in \mathrm{Im}(X)$, so that $\Pi_{V}(y)-X\beta \in \mathrm{Im}(X)$. And $y - \Pi_{V}(y) \in \mathrm{Im}(X)^{\perp}$. So, by Pythagore's theorem, we have :

$$ \Vert y-X\beta \Vert^{2} = \Vert y-\Pi_{V}(y) \Vert^{2} + \Vert \Pi_{V}(y) - X\beta \Vert^{2} \tag{$\star$} $$

Now, we need the following result :

> $$ \Pi_{V} = X({}^t X X)^{-1} {}^t X $$
>
> Sketch of proof : It is quite easy to prove that the orthogonal projection on $\mathrm{Im}(X)$ is actually given by the previous formula since we have ${}^t \Pi_{V} \Pi_{V} = \Pi_{V}$, $\Pi_{V} {}^t \Pi_{V} = \Pi_{V}$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\Pi_{V}(x) \in \mathrm{Im}(X)$.

Let $b=({}^t X X)^{-1} {}^t Xy$, we have : $\Pi_{V}(y) = Xb$. It follows that ($\star$) writes :

$$ \Vert y-Xb \Vert^{2} + \Vert Xb-X\beta \Vert^{2} \tag{$\star\star$} $$

The first term in the RHS of ($\star\star$) is ${}^t (y-Xb)(y-Xb)$ and the second term is ${}^t (\beta - b) {}^t X X (\beta - b)$. Eventually, we have :

> $$\Vert y-X\beta \Vert^{2} = {}^t (y-Xb)(y-Xb) + {}^t (\beta - b) {}^t X X (\beta - b)$$